# GarageBand: Create Apple Loop from m4a recorded piano files?

Tags: audio-recording, piano, garageband, aac-m4a

How can I import m4a files as Apple Loops? 
I love the concept of the loops but I can't always have my main pianist next to me recording and then storing it as Apple Loops.

Comment: Meanwhile, I figured out something incredibly simple: you can just drag your audio files onto GarageBand and they'll show up as individual tracks. But I believe they aren't imported into the Loop library, which is really what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure you can simply import the audio, trim it, or do whatever you need to it and then drag the "audio bubble" to the loop library. A window should pop out asking you for some settings and once you save its on your library! ;)

Hope it helps!